# is it okay if I intentionally make my Google Cloud Functions has multiple errors?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have collection and sub-collection like this

```
users/{userID}/followers/{followerID}
```

everytime a follower document is deleted in followers sub-collection, then it will trigger this firestore trigger below to decrease the `numberOfFollowers` field in user document. this is triggered when a user click unfollow button

```
exports.onDeleteFollower = functions
.firestore.document("users/{userID}/followers/{followerID}")
.onDelete((snapshot, context) => {

     // normally triggered after a user push unfollow button
     // then update the user document 

    const userID = context.params.userID;
    const updatedData = {
        numberOfFollowers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
    };

    return db.doc(`users/${userID}`).update(updatedData);

});
```

now I have a case like this ....

if a user deletes their account, then I will delete the user document ( users/{userID} ), but if I delete a user document, it will not automatically delete all documents inside its sub-collection, right

so after I delete the user document, I have another function to delete all documents inside the followers sub-collection.

but the problem is, the `onDeleteFollower` triggers function above will be executed multiple times, and it will throw error multiple times, because the user document has been deleted ( the function above will be used to a update a field in deleted user doc)

I will have this error in functions emulator

```
⚠  functions: Error: 5 NOT_FOUND: no entity to update: app: "myApp"
path <
  Element {
    type: "users"
    name: "u1-HuWQ5hoCQnOAwh0zRQM0nOe96K03"
  }
>

⚠  Your function was killed because it raised an unhandled error.
```

I actually can write a logic to check if a user document still exist or not. if exist then update `numberOfFollowers` field

but deleting a user document is very rare if compared to a user click the unfollow button, I think it is not very efficient.

I have a plan like this, I will intentionally let the errors happened. say a user has 1000 followers, then it will trigger the `onDeleteFollower` function above, then I will have 1000 function errors

my question is .....

is it okay if I have multiple errors in a short time like that? will Google Cloud Function terminates my function, or .... I don't know, I am worried something bad will happen that I don't know

as far as I know, cloud functions will automatically run the function again after it is killed, will my function always ready again after an error like that?

I can't let the follower update the organizer (user) document directly from the client app, because it is not safe. creating security rules to facilitate this is complicated and it seems error prone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered instead of setting/removing `users/{userID}/followers/{followerID}` directly, that you create a "follow request" system?

```json
"users/{userID}/followRequests/{requestID}": { // requestID would be auto-generated
  user: "{followerID}",
  follow: true // true = add user as follower, false = remove user as follower
}
```

This then allows you to use a single `onCreate` trigger to update your followers list eliminating the need for your current `onCreate` and `onDelete` triggers on `users/{userID}/followers/{followerID}`. From this function you can implement restrictions on following other users like follow limits or denying follow requests for blocked users.

```
export const newFollowRequest = functions.firestore
  .document('users/{userId}/followRequests/{requestId}')
  .onCreate(async (snap, context) => {
    const request = snap.data();
    const followingUserId = request.user;
    const followedUserId = context.params.userId;

    const db = admin.firestore();
    const userDocRef = db.doc(`users/${followedUserId}`);
    const followerDocRef = userDocRef.child(`followers/${followingUserId}`);
    // /users/${followingUserId}/following/${followedUserId} ?
    
    try {
    
      if (request.follow) {
        // Example restriction: Is the user who is attempting to follow
        //                      blocked by followedUserId?
        // await assertUserIDHasNotBlockedUserID(followedUserId, followingUserId);

        // following
        db.update(userDocRef, {
          numberOfFollowers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(1),
        });
        db.set(followerDocRef, {
          /* ... */
        });
      } else {
        // unfollowing
        db.update(userDocRef, {
          numberOfFollowers: admin.firestore.FieldValue.increment(-1),
        });
        db.delete(followerDocRef);
      }
      
      // delete this request when successful
      db.delete(snap.ref);
      
      // commit database changes
      await db.commit();

      console.log(`@${followingUserId} ${request.follow ? "followed" : "unfollowed"} @${followedUserId} successfully`);
      
    } catch (err) {
      // something went wrong, update this document with a failure reason (to show on the client);
      let failureReason = undefined;
      switch (err.message) {
        case "other user is blocked":
          failureReason = "You are blocked by @otherUser";
          break;
        case "user is blocked":
          failureReason = "You have blocked @otherUser";
          break;
      }
      
      return db.ref(snap.ref)
        .update({
          failureReason: failureReason || "Unknown server error";
        })
        .then(() => {
          if (failureReason) {
            console.log("REQUEST REJECTED: " + failureReason);
          } else {
            console.error("UNEXPECTED ERROR:", err)
          }
        },
        (err) => {
          console.error("UNEXPECTED FIRESTORE ERROR:", err);
        });
    }
  });
```

Comment: If the `followedUserId` was included in the follow request document, you could move the requests up to `/followRequests/{requestId}` rather than under `/users/{followedUserId}`.